# JBoss + Maven: Error building POM

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jboss, pom.xml, building

I am trying to launch JBoss application server - my goal is to launch it and deploy some very simple project (I'm trying to do this with "helloworld" from the original quickstarts). The problem is that I have no experience with JBoss or Maven, so I'm having terrible time for a few days and it still isn't working. I presume, that the mistake is in Maven configuration, but I don't know, what I'm supposed to rewrite / replace to repair it.

This is the exact error:

*[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
Project ID: org.jboss.component.management:jboss-dependency-management-all
Reason: POM 'org.jboss.component.management:jboss-dependency-management-all' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
org.jboss.component.management:jboss-dependency-management-all:pom:6.0.1-redhat-1
from the specified remote repositories:
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
for project org.jboss.component.management:jboss-dependency-management-all*

I was trying to follow instructions given at http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/#build-and-deploy-th%20e-quickstarts , so my only configuration of Maven was, that I copied settings.xml from quickstart directory to .m2 directory.Finally I tried to build and deploy quickstart by command "mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy", but it caused the error :-(

How to repair this mistake?

P.s.: I use Ubuntu 14.04.

---

This is how the structure of my folder with JBoss looks like:

```
.
├── InstallationLog.txt
├── InstallSummary.html
├── jboss-eap-6.2
│   ├── appclient
│   ├── bin
│   ├── bundles
│   ├── docs
│   ├── domain
│   ├── icons
│   ├── JBossEULA.txt
│   ├── jboss-modules.jar
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── modules
│   ├── standalone
│   ├── version.txt
│   └── welcome-content
├── jboss-eap-6.2.0.GA-quickstarts
│   ├── bean-validation
│   ├── bmt
│   ├── cdi-alternative
│   ├── cdi-decorator
│   ├── cdi-injection
│   ├── cdi-interceptors
│   ├── cdi-portable-extension
│   ├── cdi-stereotype
│   ├── cdi-veto
│   ├── cluster-ha-singleton
│   ├── cmt
│   ├── configure-postgresql.cli
│   ├── CONTRIBUTING.html
│   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   ├── contributor-settings.xml
│   ├── dist
│   ├── ejb-asynchronous
│   ├── ejb-in-ear
│   ├── ejb-in-war
│   ├── ejb-multi-server
│   ├── ejb-remote
│   ├── ejb-security
│   ├── ejb-security-interceptors
│   ├── ejb-throws-exception
│   ├── ejb-timer
│   ├── forge-from-scratch
│   ├── greeter
│   ├── guide
│   ├── helloworld
│   ├── helloworld-jms
│   ├── helloworld-mbean
│   ├── helloworld-mdb
│   ├── helloworld-osgi
│   ├── helloworld-rs
│   ├── helloworld-singleton
│   ├── helloworld-ws
│   ├── hibernate3
│   ├── hibernate4
│   ├── hornetq-clustering
│   ├── h2-console
│   ├── inter-app
│   ├── jax-rs-client
│   ├── jta-crash-rec
│   ├── jts
│   ├── jts-distributed-crash-rec
│   ├── kitchensink
│   ├── kitchensink-ear
│   ├── kitchensink-jsp
│   ├── kitchensink-ml
│   ├── kitchensink-ml-ear
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── logging
│   ├── logging-tools
│   ├── log4j
│   ├── mail
│   ├── numberguess
│   ├── payment-cdi-event
│   ├── picketlink-sts
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── README.html
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── RELEASE_PROCEDURE.html
│   ├── RELEASE_PROCEDURE.md
│   ├── remove-postgresql.cli
│   ├── servlet-async
│   ├── servlet-filterlistener
│   ├── servlet-security
│   ├── settings.xml
│   ├── shopping-cart
│   ├── tasks
│   ├── tasks-jsf
│   ├── tasks-rs
│   ├── temperature-converter
│   ├── template
│   ├── wicket-ear
│   ├── wicket-war
│   ├── wsat-simple
│   ├── wsba-coordinator-completion-simple
│   ├── wsba-participant-completion-simple
│   ├── xml-dom4j
│   └── xml-jaxp
└── Uninstaller
└── uninstaller.jar
```

settings.xml: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1926

pom.xml: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1927

Comment: Glad you resolved this. A hint: sometimes, when download of artifacts fails you still have some stale files in the local repository. I sometimes hat copies of 404 pages there. Then Maven thinks, oh, this thing is not available. So it helps checking directories for the artifacts in quesion in your local repository.

Comment: Great point, I didn't have any idea about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've solved this - thorough delete of all Maven files ( or files which held some deprecated info about Maven ) and installation of its newest version was the key :-)

This solution is written for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (but it should work in other versions and even other Debian-based systems too).

---

**STEP-BY-STEP SOLUTION:**

1) Completely uninstall Maven

```
sudo apt-get purge maven
```

2) Uninstall libaether package

```
sudo apt-get purge libaether-java
```

3) Uninstall libplexus packages

```
sudo apt-get purge libplexus-*
```

4) Finally, install actual Maven version from the repository

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```